# Spring AOP Transaction Management and Hibernate: undesired commits to database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions, aop

Is it possible to enable transactions for methods that making calls to DAO (data access object) methods only?

`class BusinessLayerFacade implements Facade {`

```
//no transaction handling allowed here
public X foo() {
    //do something
}

public Y changed(DomainObject myObject) {
    //do something
    //<-- start transaction
    // calling DAO 
    //do something
    // calling DAO
    //<-- end transaction
}
```

}

Allowing transactions for all methods in the `BusinessLayerFacade`  causes some undesired commits to the Database. E.g. when foo() is called an an `Exception` is thrown while executing `changed(DomainObject myObject)`, `myObject` has been commited to the database instead of reverting the changes on transaction rollback.

Any ideas?

It is defenitly an option to filter methods by name But can we please put a little more magic in there ;-) Is it possible to start a transaction on the first call of a DAO method **in**  `changed()` and start a commit on **returning from** `changed()`. If this is possible i don't have to be careful while naming new methods in the class.

Thanks, Stefan

Comment: Flush and transaction commit are not the same. Hibernate can decide to make a flush during transaction - just to synchronize its session and database state. And hibernate can decide to make a flush and then rollback transaction.

Comment: I corrected this in my question. Thanks for advise!

Answer (score 1):

A transaction is rolled back if a runtime exception is thrown. Not if an application exception is thrown. You may customize this by applying the annotation @Transactional:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=SomeException.class, noRollbackFor=SomeOtherException.class)
```

This can also be customized globally in XML, using the `rollback-for` and `no-rollback-for` attributes of the `tx:method` element.

Read The [Spring reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#transaction-declarative-txadvice-settings) for more details.

Comment: annotating a method makes AOP irrelevant

Comment: No it doesn't. It just makes it easy to customize what the aspect should do for a specific method. If you want to define a behavior globally, then use the XML attributes, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Annotations making things easily customizable is a moot point. If he was using annotations, he wouldn't need AOP, hence the irrelevancy. Even if the TX annotation-driven uses internal AOP, I don't think it's the point or desired result of the OP.

Comment: It's not irrelevant, since I *also* explained he could do it globally in XML. And knowing that you may customize it here and there using annotations is better than not knowing it, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is method level TX advice:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
   <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="changed*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="Throwable"/>
   </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethods" expression="execution(* my.package.service.*.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethods"/>
</aop:config>
```

Comment: It is defenitly an option to filter methods by name, thanks! But can we please put a little more magic in there ;-) Is ist possible to start a transaction on the first call of a DAO method **in**  `changed()` and start a commit on **returning from** `changed()`. If this is possible i don't have to be careful while naming new methods in the class.